# File not found when archiving iOS project

Tags: ios, xcode

I am trying to archive my app into an .ipa file with Xcode 4.3.2 to send to the app store but I am getting this error when attempting to archive it:

> 'KKGridView/KKGridView.h' file not found

KKGridView is a different project in my workspace producing a single target which is a static library.

When performing a regular build it works well, also when deploying to a device.

I have read alot about this issue, I have tried setting `Skip Install` to YES on the static library project but that doesn't help.
I have encountered some tips regarding user headers or something but it wasn't very clear to me since I am not very familiar with the whole headers concept of Xcode.

Should I change the setup of my workspace or is there some configuration I am missing?

Comment: Have you tried running your Build to run 'Release' instead of 'Debug'? Does it have the same error?

Comment: Yes, the same error is raised.

Comment: Could it be that this file was not added to the xcode project, or maybe accidently deleted from it? Check `Add files to project`.

Comment: It's included in another project in the workspace. A regular build works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I just copied the entire source code of the library into my project and deleted the second project.

Comment: it is pathetic how crappy Xcode 4.x is, starting with its inability to find files included on the project.